# How to handle dfa with countless states?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have a question regarding DFA:

*Design a DFA M with alphabet $\sum = \ {\{0,1,2,R}\}$ where the states remember actual sums of the number, except that the sum is reset to 0 whenever the symbol $R$ appears. Show diagrammatically how this DFA can be constructed. What is the problem with this DFA?*

One thing I do understand is that in order to remember the actual sums I would have to have the sums as states. But sums can be any number from 0 to  infinity. So would the states increase exponentially while reading the input string? How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have missed the last sentence of the question:

> What is the problem with this DFA?

The problem with this DFA is that it isn't finite (so it's not really a DFA).

A DFA is a *static* object — the only way it interacts with the environment is by switching states.

Comment: But if the input is finite, then wouldn't the sum be technically finite also?

Comment: Every natural number is finite. The set of natural numbers is infinite.